# Pyspark - Apply datetime.time function to all lines of dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, pyspark

I'm working on pyspark and I have a dataframe with two int values, corresponding to hours and minutes:

```
+------------------------+----------------------+
|HOURS                   |                   MIN|
+------------------------+----------------------+
|                       9|                    25|
|                      22|                     5|
|                      22|                     5|
|                      22|                     5|
+------------------------+----------------------+
```

I would like to create a new column of type datetime with the following code:

```
import datetime as dt
data = data.withColumn('TIME', dt.time(data["HOURS"], data["MIN"]))
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How to solve it? Thank you very much :)

Comment: `data['HOURS'].cast(IntegerType())`

Comment: Thanks @Rumoku but I obtain the same error, since the column 'HOURS' is already composed by integer.

Comment: what about minutes?

Comment: Both the columns, HOURS and MIN, contains elements of integer type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a spark `Column` type to `dt.time` and hence `dt.time` raises the `TypeError`. You need to wrap your python function into a user defined function (UDF) to pass a type `Column` to a python function:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


df = pd.DataFrame({"HOURS": [2, 5, 8], 
                   "MIN": [23, 55, 43]})

dfs = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
dfs.show()

+-----+---+
|HOURS|MIN|
+-----+---+
|    2| 23|
|    5| 55|
|    8| 43|
+-----+---+

@udf
def create_timestamp(hour, minute):
    return dt.time(hour, minute)

dfs.withColumn('TIME', create_timestamp("HOURS", "MIN")).show()

+-----+---+--------------------+
|HOURS|MIN|                TIME|
+-----+---+--------------------+
|    2| 23|Time: 2 hours, 23...|
|    5| 55|Time: 5 hours, 55...|
|    8| 43|Time: 8 hours, 43...|
+-----+---+--------------------+
```